# In Package.swift, can I reference files from other another server?

Tags: swift-package-manager

I have a git repo with Package.swift, which declares an SPM package. However I can not host the actual files that implement the package in this same repository.

These files need to be in a completely different server.

Can I reference https://otherwebsite.com/MySwiftFile1.swift as a source file in SPM Package.swift?

Comment: Just curious what's the use case here.

Comment: I actually need not a source file, but an xcframework. This question is unrelated - I was just wondering, there is no use case and no intention to store sources separate from Package.swift.